# Setting IgnoredUID for AWS for AppMesh Envoy Sidecar in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I'm configuring an ECS Task Definition to use AWS AppMesh for virtual networking. I'm using Envoy, which AWS recommends running as a sidecar; they have native support for it using the `proxyConfiguration` block in the ECS `TaskDefinition` configuration.

One of the properties available for configuration in the proxy is `IgnoredUID`. This purportedly allows the Envoy process to ignore its own traffic during proxy, without having to inspect it *using* the proxy. It's a performance enhancement. However, the docs don't describe how I might find my own version of that number. They just use the number "1337" and I haven't been able to figure out where that comes from.

The docs are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/appmesh-getting-started.html (scroll down to "Update task definitions" and see JSON section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UID that a docker process runs as can be fairly arbitrary. By default, all docker processes run with UID 0 (root). There are a few ways in which this changed:

1. By baking a different default user into the image via the [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) command in your Dockerfile
2. Specifying a user in docker's cli using `--user`
3. Setting `user` or `uid` in your ECS container definition for the sidecar:

For your case, I would assign any arbitrary UID for the container and set the same number for the `IgnoredUID` option.

Comment: great answer, thank you, I've stuck with 1337.